# jquery clone drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable

i m having a problem in appending a tag over an area.
I am tring to append the clone of #Normal_Tag1_div to #droppable after changing the id.
I also want to make that clone draggable over #droppable only .
How can i do that??

```
$('#Normal_Tag1_div').draggable({helper:'clone'});  
         $('#droppable').droppable({
           drop: function(ev,ui) {
                    clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                    $(clone).attr('id', 'newid'+count1)
                    $('#droppable').append(clone);
                    //$(clone).draggable();
                        //$('#droppable').droppable({});
                    var title = $(clone).attr('id');
                alert(title);
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$(clone).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [containment](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) option from jQuery UI Draggable. It restricts the drag to a given div.